# how to encrypt response data in filter

Tags: java, servlets, encryption, filter

i am trying encrypt response data before it written into the HttpServletResponse, so i have implemented custom response wrapper and output streram and a filter classes,

Problem is i need to encrypt whole response data once, but there is no `write(String content)` method, but there are three methods available inside ServletOutputStream class which are `write(int b)`, `write(byte[] b)` and `write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` when i run the application only one method is called `write(int b)`.

So is there any workaround to get whole response data as string, where i can call encrypt(responseData) ?

my classes looks like:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        BufferedRequestWrapper bufferedReqest = new BufferedRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);  
        BufferedServletResponseWrapper bufferedResponse = new BufferedServletResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);

        // pass the wrappers on to the next entry
        chain.doFilter(bufferedReqest, bufferedResponse);
}
```

and

```
public class BufferedServletResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private ServletOutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private MyServletOutputStream copier;

    public BufferedServletResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {        
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        LOG.info("getOutputStream");
        if (writer != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getWriter() has already been called on this response.");
        }

        if (outputStream == null) {
            outputStream = getResponse().getOutputStream();
            copier = new MyServletOutputStream(outputStream);
        }

        return copier;
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        LOG.info("getWriter");
        if (outputStream != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("getOutputStream() has already been called on this response.");
        }

        if (writer == null) {
            copier = new MyServletOutputStream(getResponse().getOutputStream());
            writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(copier, getResponse().getCharacterEncoding()), true);
        }

        return writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.flush();
        } else if (outputStream != null) {
            copier.flush();
        }
    }

    public byte[] getCopy() {
        if (copier != null) {
            return copier.getCopy();
        } else {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    }

}
```

and my custom output stream class looks like:

```
public class MyServletOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream{

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream copy;

    public MyServletOutputStream(OutputStream outputStream) {
        this.outputStream = outputStream;
        this.copy = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        LOG.info("write int");

        outputStream.write(b);
        copy.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        LOG.info("write byte[]");

        outputStream.write(b);
        copy.write(b);
    }

    public byte[] getCopy() {
        return copy.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could put each byte on it's own into [`Cipher#update(byte[1])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#update%28byte[]%29) and later get the final result. Or via some cipher stream

Comment: Wonder if a `CipherOutputStream` here would help? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html

Comment: @Qwerky thank you for quick response,  any exampl how can I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem by this way:

1. created a custom ByteArrayOutputStream and PrintWriter instance in response wrapper class.
2. modified getOutputStream() and getWriter() method to use custom instance created in step 1.
3. finally, in filter after doFilter() statement, retrieved response data from custom writer and output stream. and written encrypted data to original response.

here is how response wrapper looks like:

```
public class BufferedServletResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

        private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream);

    public BufferedServletResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        super(response);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        LOG.info("getOutputStream");

        return new ServletOutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                LOG.info("write int");

                outputStream.write(b);
            }

            @Override
            public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
                LOG.info("write byte[]");

                outputStream.write(b);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
        LOG.info("getWriter");
        return writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.flush();
        } else if (outputStream != null) {
            outputStream.flush();
        }
    }

    public String getResponseData() {
        return outputStream.toString();
    }

}
```

and doFilter() looks like:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        BufferedServletResponseWrapper bufferedResponse = new BufferedServletResponseWrapper(
                httpServletResponse);

        // pass the wrappers on to the next entry
        chain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, bufferedResponse);

        String responseData = bufferedResponse.getResponseData();
        String encryptedResponseData = encrypt(responseData);
        OutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(encryptedResponseData.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

String str= new String( bufferedResponse .getCopy());

This will give you the string of the data in outputStream. I can see in your code you are writing bytes to out as well as copier. This copier can also be modified later.

```
String encStr=Encrypt(str); // your encryption logic.

ServletOutputStream out= response.getOutputStream();

out.write(encStr.getByte()); //adding your encrypted data to response 
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: thanks for answering. but you have to pass custom output stream and writer not the original one.

Comment: I doubt that your outputStream in doFilter will contain response data as well as the encoded data appended at the end even though you are using custom outputStreams. I feel like you need a fake writer to come over this. Please correct me if wrong.